# Animation Nodes: Distribute N amount of objects taking into account their length

Tags: animation-nodes

I have 3 objects of varying lengths which I want to distribute in random order to a grid or matrix of certain dimensions. If I do the basic matrix distribute then the meshes overlap.
[image: Please see the image below for clarification]

Method of distribution is not important just that the objects do not overlap(only one dimension varies ) and that there are N of them in a row or a column. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with these 2 nested loops:

[image]

result:

[image]

How it works:

The inner loop (calculate x positions) calculates the x positions by reassigning the currentX value in the loop by just adding the size of each object.

The outer loop just calls the inner loop for each y line and give it the right y-value.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much it works perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome 